# Autorotation disabled after setting selectedIndex property of UITabBarControllers (SDK bug?)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitabbarcontroller, autorotate

**The problem.**  I'm getting a very strange error in my application.   I have a UITabBarController with several view controllers for the tabs.  In the view controllers I have implemented autorotation via `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and it was working fine until I made the following change.

I implemented swipe gestures in the view controllers to change between tabs.  This is accomplished via the following code.

```
- (void)onSwipeLeft {
  int _count = [[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] count];
  int i = self.view.tag - 1;
  if (i < _count - 1) {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = (i + 1) % _count;
  }
}
```

And similarly for `onSwipeRight`.

Now, autorotation only works *until you swipe left or right*.  After that, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is never called at all.

**See also.**

- In [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/66875-unusual-error-setselectedindex-begindisablinginterfaceautorotation.html#post290116) the identical problem is described.  I also sometimes see 
  a log message like the following: `-[UIWindow beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation] overflow on <UIWindow: 0x1410e0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x141190>>. Ignoring.`  I can't find any other information about this.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111638/iphone-sdk-tab-bar-auto-rotate-on-orientation-change) seems to be describing the same problem.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791048/popviewcontroller-does-not-autorotate-back-to-allowed-orientation) seems to be describing a similar problem but with `popViewController:`.  Note that the bug has been there since SDK 3.2.

**What to do?**  It seems like a bug in the SDK which is still present in 4.1.  Has anyone found a workaround?  It seems like a common scenario.

Comment: does your UITabViewController conform to auto rotate? since it is the parent of the other views, it has to allow rotation as well.

Comment: I tried subclassing UITabViewController and returning `YES` in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have thought of this earlier.

Create `UIWindow+ensureAutorotation.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIWindow (ensureAutorotation)

- (void)beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation;
- (void)endDisablingInterfaceAutorotation;

@end
```

And `UIWindow+ensureAutorotation.m`:

```
#import "UIWindow+ensureAutorotation.h"

@implementation UIWindow (ensureAutorotation)

- (void)beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation {}
- (void)endDisablingInterfaceAutorotation{}

@end

// of course this can be added as a simple category, rather than .h .m files
```

Comment: can you explain why this is a solution...an empty method?

Comment: This might cause secondary effects, since you are overwriting a UIKit method inside an extension, disregarding what the original method does. Doing that is not recommended, further more, doing it inside an extension, is very obscure because you don't actually know which implementation will take place. Imagine if you provide more than one extension that overwrites the same method... what will happen?